# How can we pass encrypted password in SQL connection string on PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How can we pass encrypted password in SQL connection string on PowerShell?

Unable to connect SQL server with NT AUTHORITY\ SYSTEM account. What teps need to be taken to connect to SQL Server with NT Authority\System account?
As checked, I installed PSTools and extract all files in specific location and ran cmd.
With below cmd
psexec -i -s ssms.exe
After running the above cmd, I got :
couldn't install
Access denied

Answer (score 0):

You dont say much about the client and what you are supposed to achieve. The part about psexec is quite hard for me to understand.

You can use credentials in two ways from local network, sql login and windows login. I assume you are attemting to use windows login.

If you, from a windows computer, run a console app or desktop app, you will connect as the user who started the app. In normal terms, you.

Since you get "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM", I guess you want to try as similar as possible like a Windows Service. My recommendation is to start the service as a named user "AD\MyServiceAccount". You give access to this user in SQL server.

I recommend you to read about the differences of:

- NT AUTHORITY\System
- NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
- AD Account

If you are not trying to debug/build a service, but just want to get some sql server data in an desktop application. Use regular tools and your personal account. If not, sql login.

If you want to use the Computer Account, you should use add AD\$ComputerAccount to ACL list on SQLserver.

Note: AD being the name of your Active Directory.